# Populating multiple user controls with database fields

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

Can anyone understand what it is I am trying to do here?

I have a main Windows form with a **TabControl** on a panel. Inside the ***contacts*** tab I want to dynamically generate new user controls that I have created containing various textfields and labels that should display a company's contact and their details (phone, mobile, full name, notes etc.).

This is where it gets confusing. The main **customers** form has a combobox which allows for **search** of customers within a customers database (MySQL). once selected the fields in the ***customer details*** tab are updated.

I want to be able to create a instances of the user control in the ***Contacts*** tab after each search from the main **Customers** form. These Contacts are in another table connected via foreign key ***Customer Code***. I understand that the number of UC instances created are based on a count of all instances of a specific ***Customer Code***, but how to put this into code escapes me.

Apologies if this question has already been asked before.

If anymore detail is required, please let me know.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use a DataGridView populated from a generated SQL query based on the search?

Comment: This question is a little too big in scope. Do you want to know how to dynamically generate `UserControls`, or are you asking about the `SQL` aspect as well? Additionally, to get help on SO you need to show what you've done, not ask for code samples. Try to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as shown in the link.

Comment: I am not asking for an actual code sample but rather some explanation if possible. I understand what is expected of me of the SQL but am unsure whether to get the DataReader to input the data straight into the UserControl class or in the Customers class after the UC is instantiated.

Comment: Read the link @Sach sent you. Also read the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. StackOverflow is for answering **specific** programming questions; it is not for advice on *how* to implement a feature nor is it a code writing service.